# @Autowired annotation not working for one @Controller class and working for others

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have three `@RestController` classes, for two of them the `@Autowired` is injecting the bean, but for one it is not. I don't know what the issue is, as few hours ago the same code was working fine.
package com.learn.service;

```
package com.learn.service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class RoleService {

    @Autowired
    private RoleJpaRepository roleJpaRepository;

    public List<Role> findAll(){
        return roleJpaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

the controller for Role

```
package com.learn.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/roles")
public class RoleController {

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private List<Role> findAll() {
        System.out.println(roleService);  // roleService is null here and NullPointerException is thrown from below method call.
        return roleService.findAll();
    }

}
```

Configuration class for Service

```
package com.learn.springConfig;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.learn.service")
public class ServiceConfig {

    public ServiceConfig() {
        super();
    }

}
```

the runner

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({
    ContextConfig.class,
    PersistenceJpaConfig.class,
    ServiceConfig.class,
    WebConfig.class,
    SecurityConfig.class
})
public class WebservicesLearningApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebservicesLearningApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

For the same configurations, the controller for User is working fine whose Service layer exists in the same package as that of Role.

```
package com.learn.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        System.out.println(userService);
        List<User> users = userService.findAll();   
        return users;
    }
```

Service layer

```
package com.learn.service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

    public List<User> findAll(){
        return userJpaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Accessing the `localhost:8080/api/users` is successful but `localhost:8080/api/roles` gives NullPointerException

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.learn.controller.RoleController.findAll(RoleController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]............
```

**Update1:**
Web configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.learn.controller"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    public WebConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Optional<HttpMessageConverter<?>> convertFound = converters.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter).findFirst();
        if(convertFound.isPresent()) {
            final AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = (AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) convertFound.get();
            converter.getObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            converter.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        }
    } 


}
```

screenshot of project structure
[image: project structure]

**Update2 : I tried using the same UserService using @Autorired in a jUnit test case, and everything is working there. No nullpointer exception.**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceJpaConfig.class, ContextConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RoleTest {

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService ;

    @Test
    public void checkIfAllRolesCanBeRetrieved() {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll();
        Assert.assertNotNull(roles);
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your project package strucuture?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn updated the question.

Comment: There's nothing different between `RoleController` and `UserController`.

Comment: Yes, there is no difference, but still different behaviour.

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild, this is related to cache issue I think

Comment: What is in your `WebConfig`? Seems it is configuration for `Controller`s?

Comment: @TKJohn plz check the update. Its a configuration class

Comment: Can you remove the component scan in all places. The class which contains the main method has a ComponentScan (SpringBootApplication annotation has ComponentScan annotation) annotation on it. I think adding ComponentScan in n different places is causing this issue.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn clean and rebuild didn't worked

Comment: Build and runs OK for me. Now I am thinking about the `@Service` annotation in `RoleService`, is this the `Spring` one?

Comment: @IndraneelBende but how the SpringBootApplication's componentScan will scan the packages if we don't provide the package name?

Comment: yes, @Service is of type org.springframework.stereotype.Service

Comment: Your main class is in the package com.learn, Thats what SpringBootApplication's ComponentScan will try to scan. So all your beans will get instantiated.

Comment: and btw does @ComponentScan("com.learn.service") work. You have not specified any element such as - basePackages. Should'nt it be @ComponentScan(basePackages= "com.learn.service")

Comment: Just to mention, with `@SpringBootApplication`, you don't need all the `Config` files. `SpringBoot` will take care all the componet. They are for `Spring MVC` not boot. But this should not cause the issue, though.

Comment: @puspen If the above does not work. Can u post ur project on github. Happy to take a look.

Comment: Can you share the package import statements for `@Service` in `RestService` and  `RestController` in  `RoleController`?

Comment: The complete code is on GitHub. Kindly clone from https://github.com/Puspendert/Spring-webservices.git 
thanks

Comment: With the github code, removed security part, the `UserController` and `UserService` works fine. No null injection happens.

Comment: @TKJohn the null injection is with RoleService in RoleController. UserController is already working fine.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake here. But *both* `RoleController` and `UserController` are accessible, no null happens, on my local.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me! in my case I had a controller using  service,The service used a method of a class that did not have a @service,@controller or another annotation and I inject in service then when I use parent service error null occurred.

I hope that it will be used

Comment: I am accessing a Controller, which is using Service and which internally is Using Repository. I have annotated each component class.